# is async/await slower than promises?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Is using async/await slower in some scenarios than using promises?

Consider such code using promises

```
function foo() {
    const p1 = new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res('first'), 2000));
    const p2 = new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res('second'), 2000));
    p1.then(console.log);
    p2.then(console.log);
}
foo()
```

After 2000ms `'first'` and then `'second'` gets print out to the console.

The same code using async/await

```
async function foo() {
        const p1 = await new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res('first'), 2000));
        const p2 = await new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res('second'), 2000));
        console.log(p1);
        console.log(p2);
    }
foo();
```

with async/await it takes 4000ms to print `'first'` and `'second'`

Comment: It is not the same code. The first snippet runs two promises in parallel when the second one does it sequentially. Async / await cannot be slower than promises because it is based on promises, they are just the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your equivalent of the first snippet in `async / await` is wrong, should be:

```js
async function foo() {
        const p1 = new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res('first'), 2000));
        const p2 = new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res('second'), 2000));
        
        const result = await Promise.all([p1,p2]);
        console.log(result[0]);
        console.log(result[1]);
    }
    
foo();
```

The first snippet you have runs the promises concurrently, the second synchronously. That's why `await` should be used with good care and knowledge.

**CAVEAT**

As pointed by @Bergi, bear in mind `Promise.all` is all or nothing, so if one promise fails it will reject immediately, which is not the case in your first snippet.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: This still isn't really equivalent to the first snippet, which still logged a result if only one of the promises was rejected. And of course `foo` also returns something very different.

Comment: @Bergi, you're right. However, I think the OP's question relates to equivalence in terms of performance and not error handling. I'll update my answer with the caveat anyway.